# No network devices available - wired connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

There are countless similar problems on the forums for wireless connection which most of them have been solved.

My problem is different in that Im trying to connect with a wire cable and ubuntu 16.04 sees no devices.

The internet works seamlessly on Windows 10.

When I check for `ifconfig` it does not even list `eth0`, only `lo` content.

Suggesstions please?

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` output:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168]
```

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`

```
iHR linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic          4.4.0-64.85                                    
amd64        (no description available)
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux bartek-desktop 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 
UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you connect with a cable?

Comment: I connect to the router with a cable (not wifi). It's a desktop computer.

Comment: Did you setup your connection in Network Manager? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Ok, I will in a moment; I've now checked the internet on my laptop (same ubuntu version) and is working fine.

Comment: Is this the full output?

Comment: Yes, the full output.

Comment: Can you temporarily connect to the internet some other way on this comp?

Comment: On windows10 the same comp.

Comment: I see that there is a problem with the kernel. Can you post output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: If it does not output anything, post `uname -a`.

Comment: @Pilot6 do you think upgrading to 16.10 or maybe reverting back to 14.04 could resolve the problem?

Comment: A fresh install of 16.04 should fix it. Something is wrong with the kernel. The `r8169` is not available. It could be an interrupted upgrade or something like that.

Comment: Reinstallation of 16.04 worked. Thanks! I would be happy to vote your answer up as well as make it a solved case if you post it as the answer.

Comment: I do not think posting an answer suggesting to re-install would be really helpful for anyone else.